# Get from JSON Value

Tags: json, xpages

I have two JSON.
The first one is the value.
EDIT:

```
[{
"objectDimStr": ["Laenge in m: 8630",
"Anzahl Fahrstreifen in : 4",
"Anzahl Bruecken in : 5",
"Anzahl Bauwerke in : 5"],
"objectDim": {
    "value": "5",
    "unit": "",
    "dimension": "Anzahl Bauwerke"
},
"objectType": "Strecke Landstrasse",
"objectSpec": ["inkl. Entw\u00E4sserungsanlagen",
"begleitender Geh-\/Radweg"],
"object": "Strassenverkehrswege"
}]
```

The second one is the configuration.

```
[{
    "name": "Objekt",
    "propertyName": "object"
},
{
    "name": "Objekttyp",
    "propertyName": "objectType"
},
{
    "name": "Kennzahlen(Einheit: Wert)",
    "propertyName": "objectDimStr"
},
{
    "name": "Objektspezifikation",
    "propertyName": "objectSpec"
}]
```

Now I want display this in a table.

```
<table
id="tablePager"
class="table table-striped table-condensed mat-table table-response">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <xp:repeat
            id="repTabHeader"
            rows="10000"
            value="#{javascript:compositeData.TableConfObj.Config;}"
            var="confName">
            <th class="table-width valign-top">
                <xp:text value="#{javascript:confName.name}"></xp:text>
            </th>
        </xp:repeat>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <xp:repeat
        id="repTabBody"
        rows="10000"
        value="#{javascript:compositeData.Obj;}"
        var="entry">
        <tr>
            <xp:repeat
                id="repTabBodyVal"
                rows="10000"
                value="#{javascript:compositeData.TableConfObj.Config;}"
                var="confProperty">
                <td class="table-width valign-top">
                    <xp:inputTextarea
                        id="inputTextarea1"
                        readonly="true">
                        <xp:this.value>
                            <![CDATA[#{javascript:
                                var propName = confProperty.propertyName;
                                if ((propName == null || propName == "")) {
                                    return "";
                                } else {
                                    var propValue = entry.get(propName);
                                    if ((propValue == null || propValue == "")) {
                                        return "";
                                    } else {
                                        if (propValue.getClass() == "class java.util.ArrayList"){
                                            return propValue.join(", ");
                                        } else {
                                            return propValue;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }]]>
                        </xp:this.value>
                    </xp:inputTextarea>
                </td>
            </xp:repeat>
        </tr>
    </xp:repeat>
</tbody>
```

The problem is the 'entry.get(propName)'. In one case I get the Value from the JSON. In another case I get an error.

> Script interpreter error, line=6, col=143: [TypeError] Error calling
>   method 'get(java.lang.String)' on an object of type 'String
>   [JavaScript Object]'

How can I get the value from the JSON without the get. I don't know the name of the JSON-Entries, only in the configuration-JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I've run into this before, but I don't recall the solution. Will keep racking my brain to try to remember how I solved it.

In the meantime, you could try this: `var propName:java.lang.String = confProperty.propertyName;`

EDIT: actually, the error is indicating that the `entry` variable is a String, rather than a JSONObject, thus you can't call the get method. Initially I thought it didn't like the argument to the method call. Not sure what you setup for custom properties of the custom control to pass in the Obj, could be an issue there. If you added this, it might do the trick:

```
var jsonEntry = toJson(entry);
var propValue = jsonEntry.get(propName);
```

Comment: Okay. compositeData.Obj ist type 'object'.
But they don't know JSON.
[ReferenceError] 'JSON' not found
What's wrong!

Comment: typeof from entry is com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.JsonJavaObject.

Comment: Doh, it should have been `toJson(entry)`. But if the type is JsonJavaObject then it should be fine. Must be something else.

Comment: Should it be: `var attributeObj = entry.getAsJson("attributeObject"); var propValue = attributeObj.get(propName);` ? Is there a typo in your paste above `"attributeObject": [{` with an extra square bracket?

Comment: I've edit the JSON. Without attributeObject, only the value.